# Neo4j Create node if no relationship exists

Tags: neo4j, tree, graph-databases

From the MERGE documentation

```
MATCH (person:Person)
MERGE (city:City { name: person.bornIn })
MERGE (person)-[r:BORN_IN]->(city)
RETURN person.name, person.bornIn, city
```

The problem is, I want to create a Relationship and a Node, if the RELATIONSHIP does not exist, but in my graph all the nodes are identical so the second step would not create a new Node.

Since my graph is a tree I know that if the relationship i'm looking for does not exist, the node also does not exist.

Giving the nodes  unique identifiers is not helpful as it would just be the path from the root node to the one i want to create. If I replace MERGE with CREATE it will create redundant nodes that are not connected to the tree. Since you cant use MERGE with WHERE, is there a way to do the equivalent of:

```
MERGE (nextpos:Position) WHERE NOT (nextpos)--()
```

Which would create a node if there are no nodes without connections, allowing me in the next step to create the needed relationship. Or should I just remove all the redundant nodes afterwards? That would seem very hacky and I am hoping for an elegant solution.

Comment: "From the MERGE documentation ...." That cypher query is just there to confuse, it has nothing to do with the question you are asking. Instead, you need to focus on giving more details about your db schema and what you are exactly trying to do. See [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @m0hithreddy Thanks. I have a million strings of chess game notation where each move is separated by a space.
Ex of string: "e4 e5 Nc3 Nc6". Each of these strings is accompanied by a string containing information about the game.

In essence I want to build a game tree where the nodes are positions and 
the relationships are moves.

There would also be a game information node for each game, which would point to the last move of the game in the game tree.

Comment: @m0hithreddy The position node wouldn't store the current board position and I don't care about transposition. I can elaborate on the points if something is unclear.

Comment: @m0hithreddy Also if it is unclear, if I have four games:
"e4 e5 Nf3" "Game1Info"
"e4 e5 Bc4" "Game2Info"
"e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 "Game3Info"
"e4 e5 Nf3 Nc6 "Game4Info"
The graph will be: https://ibb.co/chzRBGG

Comment: What is the issue with the condition on merging? The end result will be the same. If the relationship does not exist, create it. If it does exist, it'll still exist after the merge.

Comment: @Prog If I understand correctly, suppose if we are having game5 "e4 e5 Bc4 Nc6 Nf3" (lets assume this game is possible) along with the given 4 games. then you wont form Bc4->Nc6->Nf3->Bc5 cycle, instead you create a new node Nc6 which is connected to Bc4.

Comment: @m0hithreddy You are correct even if the position repeats in a different move order i still create a new node. Small note: The nodes don't have names. In the image I added larger text, because the relationship names seemed small.

Comment: @manonthemat I can't create a relationship before I create a node to connect to can I? I can't use merge to make a position node since they are identical in labels and properties. If I create a node before trying to make a relationship with merge I don't know if I will need the node and might have too many nodes that will all form relationships on the next merge.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend changing your DB schema. If all the nodes are having identical properties, I don't know how are you planning to perform `MATCH` later on. All nodes might be identical to user but neo4j has a `<id>` field, which is unique to each entity (node and relationship).

Anyways coming to the problem, As far as I understand you need to check if a particular node is already connected to another particular node. Since you didn't give the entities properties I assume some properties here.

**DB elements**

```
(:Position {position: prev_move})-[:Move {move: next_move}]->(:Position {position: next_move})
```

**Cypher Query**

```
MATCH (n: Position {position: prev_move})
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[rel:Move {move: next_move}]->(:Position {position: next_move))
CALL apoc.do.when(rel is NULL, 
  "CREATE (next: Position {position : next_move}) CREATE (n)-[:Move {move: next_move}]->(next) RETURN next", 
  "", {n:n})
YEILD value
RETURN n
```

**EDIT**

You might need a different `MATCH`ing condition to get the exact node you are looking for. `MATCH (n: Position {position: prev_move})` will yield in multiple nodes. Please fell free to update the matching condition, rest remains same.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I know this seems arbitrary, but I'm kind of playing around with it. So if I changed the schema to include let's say an evaluation of the position and a position identifier. Would that make it easier?

Comment: The problem is that I would have to compute those for each game, which is costly, especially when there are a lot of games that are similar at the start. So even if I had the database constructed, what would I do when I get another 1000000 games to insert? I wouldn't want to recompute positions for each move of the games. I would like to see if parts of the games are already in the database and insert them.

Comment: An example of an intended query would be: For each node with evaluation higher than +3 return the number of games "under" the node.

Comment: I guess I fell into the XY problem again. Sorry.

Comment: @Prog Yes, modeling chess game is not so straightforward. You can walk upto a white board and chalk out what are your requirements and which schema suits you the best.